# Java upload file with REST Internal server error

Tags: java, web-services, rest, servlets, jboss

I have a server and a client where I try to upload a file from the client to the server and I get the following error:  `Response: Internal Server Error`

Below is my code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{    
        try{
            ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();

            config.getClasses().add(MultiPartWriter.class);
            Client client = Client.create(config);



            WebResource resource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/de.ServerReceiver/rest/upload");

            File f = new File("C:/1.txt");          
            FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(f);
            byte[] con = new byte[(int)f.length()];

            fs.read(con);
            FormDataMultiPart form1 = new FormDataMultiPart();

            FormDataBodyPart fdp = new FormDataBodyPart("content", MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
            form1.bodyPart(fdp);


            String response = resource.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).post(String.class, form1);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); 
            }
        }
}
```

Server:

```
@Path("/upload")

public class Server {

    private static final String SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER = "C://";

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)

    public Response uploadFile(
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition contentDispositionHeader) {



        String filePath = "C://" + contentDispositionHeader.getFileName();

        // save the file to the server
        saveFile(fileInputStream, filePath);

        String output = "File saved to server location : " + filePath;

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }

    // save uploaded file to a defined location on the server

    private void saveFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String serverLocation) {

        try {
            OutputStream outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outpuStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            outpuStream.flush();
            outpuStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the web.xml, as you can see I have set the url-pattern to /rest/*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>de.ServerReceiver</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>de.ServerReceiver</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The client tries to connect to the server by using the following uri: `'http://localhost:8080/de.ServerReceiver/rest/upload'`

I get the following error :

```
sdadacom.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: POST http://localhost:8080/de.ServerReceiver/rest/upload returned a response status of 500 Internal Server Error
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:688)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570)
    at de.ClientSide.ClientSide.main(ClientSide.java:82)
```

Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: Check the log. The reason for the server error is logged there.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this:

```
outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("C://"));
```

It means that you want to save the received file as "C://", which does not make sense, because "C://" is a directory, not a file.

Comment: You are right to this, I fixed it but the problem still remains. I am not able to connect to the server

Comment: Please update the question with the new error that you are seeing. Do you have the exception stack trace on the server side?

Comment: The error is the same. At the client part if you chck I have this: System.out.println("Response: " + clientResp.getClientResponseStatus());

...This prints the following: Response: Internal Server Error... I cannot connect to the server.

Comment: Is it possible to print the content of variable `serverLocation` in the `saveFile` method?

Comment: Since it is a string yes, I have done it many times. I changed abit the client part and I updated the post with the error. The error is at the end

Comment: Ok, I would like to see what is the value of `serverLocation`. I just want to make sure that when you append the value of `serverLocation` to "C://" it produces a valid filename.

Comment: I believe that the problem is at the client part. I cannot connect to the server at all. Even if I don't call the saveFile(fileInputStream, filePath); I get the same error. I think that the problem is at the final URI. Propably it hasn't the appropriate form. I have tried just to print a simple string at the server side and i can't

Comment: Try change `FormDataBodyPart fdp = new FormDataBodyPart("content", MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);` to `FormDataBodyPart fdp = new FormDataBodyPart("content", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);`

Comment: Again this error : com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: POST http://localhost:8080/de.ServerReceiver/rest/upload returned a response status of 500 Internal Server Error
 at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:676)
 at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
 at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:563)
 at de.ClientSide.ClientSide.main(ClientSide.java:93)

Comment: If you look at the error, you can see that the client says that it receives a response with status code 500 from the server. This means that the client can connect to the server. It is just that the server encounters an unexpected error while processing the request. Now, change `FormDataBodyPart("content", MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);` to `FormDataBodyPart("file", "contentOfTheFile", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);`

Comment: I have tried to replace it with FormDataBodyPart("file", "contentOfTheFile", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN); but eclipse doesn't accept it. It says that arguments cannot match because it can accept (String,String). I have tried this: FormDataBodyPart("file", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN); but again the same error

Comment: Which version of Jersey are you using? I can see three arguments constructor https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/FormDataBodyPart.html. Try `FormDataBodyPart("file", "contentOfTheFile")`.

Comment: I am using 1.18 Jersey and jersey-multipart-1.8.jar. I have tried this: FormDataBodyPart("file", "contentOfTheFile"); But again the same error.

Comment: See the server log to see exactly why the server cannot process your request. Then, update your question with the server log.